# C++ `auto` keyword for POD types

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Is there any advantages (performance or anything else) for using `auto` for POD-types in C++11?

I.e.:

```
auto result = false;
```

instead of:

```
bool result = false;
```

?

Comment: There is a good article from Herb Sutter about it here: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Yes, type deduction always infers the right type for you.

Comment: The only advantage of using auto is in situations where the type is inferred based on the definition: for(auto it =vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) Where vec is std::vector<int> and it is std::vector<int>:iterator it. Its only purpose is for readability. Correct me if im completely wrong someone

Comment: @TimLayne in non-POD types `auto` is not only for readability, but for correctness of code. If you change your data type, you will not forget to change all occurences for types of assignments.

Comment: @vladon sry I thought that was implied in my first sentence probably should have grouped my last and first sentence together